# Auth::login Returns null

Tags: php, laravel

why im getting null when i dd Auth::login? but when i dd $user it has the correct attribute. I think Auth::login is not working for me, bit the conditional role is working

this is my controller function

public function logincheck(Request $request) {
$user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();

```
    if ($user && $request->password === $user->password) {
        Auth::login($user);
        if ($user->role == 'System') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard'); // Redirect admins to the admin dashboard route
        }
        else if($user->role == 'RestoAdmin'){
            return redirect()->route('restoadmin.restodashboard');
        }
        return "okay";
    } else {
        return "not okay";
    }
}
```

i tried many methods but still no luck

Comment: `$request->password === $user->password` learn abou hashing

Comment: i dont use hash at the moment because im strill trying,. on my database its not hashed

Comment: Login return void, this is normal. What you want to be returned?

Comment: Have you configured the authentication? Also, you should have the correct driver and the user provider set in your config/auth.php file and ensure that your User model implements the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable interface.

Comment: You can try to use Auth::attempt https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#:~:text=passed%20to%20the-,Auth%3A%3Aattempt,-method%20when%20attempting . This should return true if the credentials matched. In your case:

Auth::attempt($request->only(['password'])) // returns true/false